# Issues with Ruby's defined? operator in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, operators, defined

I have an instance method on my Writer class that uses the defined? operator to check and see if posted_posts is defined:

```
def performance_score
  logger.debug posted_posts
  logger.debug defined?(posted_posts)
  unless defined?(posted_posts)
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

In my controller I have a writers instance defined as follows:

```
@writers = Writer.select("writers.*, p.total_posts, p.posted_posts").joins(...)
```

When I call @writers.performance_score, from the first logger.debug line it says I have 4 posted_posts, but the second prints out nil. Furthermore, it goes into the unless section instead of the else.

To test this, I stub out the posted_posts to 4. This prints out 4 from the first logger.debug line and the second logger.debug says it is defined as a method. Furthermore, it does go into the else.

Can you please help me understand why this is failing in my Rails application?

Comment: The `@writers = @writers.select` looks interesting. What is `@writers` (before and after the select)? Normally, we'd use something like a `Writer has_many :total_posts` which would let ActiveRecord handle `respond_to? :total_posts` with `true`.

Comment: Just a minor note -- `unless / else` is unclear and can always be rewritten as `if / else`.

Comment: I added the .joins(...) to my initial question to make it a little more clear what I'm doing. Here's the actual joins if that helps:

    `.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT writer_id,
        count(*) as total_posts,
        sum(case when state = 'posted' then 1 else 0 end) 
          as posted_posts,
        sum(case when state = 'rejected' then 1 else 0 end) 
          as rejected_posts,
        max(created_at) as last_created_post
      FROM posts
      WHERE customer_id != 11
      GROUP BY writer_id) as p ON p.writer_id = writers.id")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely failing in reality because the relation returned from your AREL `select` statement uses `method_missing` magic to return a value from the call. This is not the same thing as being `defined`. When you mock/stub the "method" on your test object it is likely using the `define_method` function which is creating a defined function.

This may do what you want instead.

```
if respond_to?(:posted_posts)
  ...
else
  ...
end
```

Comment: Do you have a suggestion that you think would work to get me the desired result?

Comment: Have you tried using `respond_to?`? It seems pretty likely that AREL would setup a proper `respond_to?` to go with its `method_missing`.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and speedy responses, but `respond_to?` returns false.

Comment: Maybe `respond_to_missing?`.

Comment: Actually Andrew, your answer worked perfectly. I had forgotten the colon before posted_posts. I ended up using has_attribute? because it seems more specific to what I was looking for, but thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

don't use the same variable name after u query the AR abject,

`@results = @writers.select("writers.*, p.total_posts, p.posted_posts")`

then call `@results.performance_score` in your controller

Comment: That's pretty standard practice for chaining scopes together.Look at this example of Ryan Bates:
    
    `def index
      @products = @products.includes(:category).page(params[:page])
    end`

Comment: I changed my query to prevent any other confusion.